# TFS 2018 Upgrade Process

Tags: upgrade, team-foundation-server, microsoft

I'm currently using **TFS 2018 (16.122.27102.1)** and I'd like to Upgrade to **2018 3.2**. Is it possible to do an **in-place upgrad**e or do I need to ***uninstall my existing instance*** - reboot - then perform the **2018 3.2 install**?

There's a lot of instructions out there for major upgrades, 2015 - 2018 but nothing for what im trying to perform, at least from what I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to upgrade my server by downloading the latest version (for me this was 2018 Update 3.2) and double clicking the new file to initiate the install. I did not need to uninstall my current version of 2018 to perform the upgrade. After clicking the install file TFS created/overwrote the current files/folders. After that the install/config prompt for TFS opened where I specified that this was an upgrade and I have existing databases. I clicked through and initiated the upgrade. Thankfully i didn't run into many issues and it was a pretty simple process.